# * Where: Script '/Users/edv-it/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1159

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

> : Error: Type 'EditableTextContextMenuBuilder' not found.
> ../…/properties/text_field_props.dart:14
> final EditableTextContextMenuBuilder? contextMenuBuilder;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> : Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
> ../…/src/firebase_app.dart:18
> FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
>
> ```
>                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> : Error: No named parameter with the name 'useSafeArea'.
> ../…/lib/dropdown_search.dart:578
> useSafeArea: widget.popupProps.modalBottomSheetProps.useSafeArea,
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> : Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
> ../…/material/bottom_sheet.dart:680
> Future<T?> showModalBottomSheet<T>({
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> : Error: Property 'context' cannot be accessed on 'OverlayState?' because it is potentially null.
> ../…/lib/dropdown_search.dart:603
>
> - 'OverlayState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart' ('../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/overlay.dart').
>   package:flutter/…/widgets/overlay.dart:1
>   Try accessing using ?. instead.
>   var overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
>   ^^^^^^^
>
> : Error: No named parameter with the name 'contextMenuBuilder'.
> ../…/widgets/selection_widget.dart:471
> contextMenuBuilder: widget.popupProps.searchFieldProps.contextMenuBuilder,
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> : Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
> ../…/material/text_field.dart:287
> : Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
> ../…/material/text_field.dart:287
> const TextField({
> ^^^^^^^^^
> : Error: 'EditableTextContextMenuBuilder' isn't a type.
> ../…/properties/text_field_props.dart:14
> final EditableTextContextMenuBuilder? contextMenuBuilder;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> 3
>
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> > Process 'command '/Users/edv-it/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> * Try:
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> > Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 17s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

how to fix it , i already 'flutter clean' and using 'flutter doctor -v' ?

Comment: there is no problem with flutter, but there are errors in your code.

Comment: can you include your code?

Comment: how to fix it, I cant install or run the code

Comment: which part should I include? because the program can't detect the error.

Comment: there seem lot of errors in your code,have you copy pasted it or its your own code?

Comment: too much code i have

Comment: can i send u file zip

Comment: are you using vscode?

Comment: yap, thats right. please help me

Comment: yes you can send

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.